# How do I prevent pop up dialog appearing when connecting an encrypted disk?

Tags: encryption, 19.04, gnome-shell, disk, external-hdd

Every time I connect an external disk with an encrypted partition a fullscreen pop up dialog appears:

> Enter a passphrase to unlock the volume

I usually do not want to decrypt this partition so the message is disruptive.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and GNOME Shell 3.32.1.

In **Settings > Devices > Removable Media** I have **Never prompt to start programs on media insertion** checked, but the pop up still appears.

How can I prevent these dialogs?

---

Edit: An answer below explains how to disable automount altogether. This is an improvement, though I would ideally like to enable automount and not decrypt encrypted volumes by default.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify a bit. You have to decrypt it before you can use it. If you don't plan on using it why would you plug it in?

Comment: It is a disk with multiple volumes. Only one on encrypted.

Comment: Got it, so the real question could be "how to only auto-mount unencrypted partitions"?

Answer (score 4):

I got this working in Ubuntu 18.04, so hopefully this will translate to 19.04:

Run **dconf-editor** and search for *automount*. You will see (2) settings, both under */org/gnome/desktop/media-handling*: **automount** and **automount-open**. Switch **automount** to *off*.

If you need to mount these devices, you can always go into **Disks** and mount them from there.

Comment: Thanks. I used the command line version `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false` and it does just what it says :)